# Self join the table/view received from a subquery

Tags: oracle, inner-join, rdbms, self-join

I was wondering, can we self join the table/view that we get back from a subquery?
If yes, then how?

I came up with an approach to apply inner join on the same subquery like:

```
SELECT attributes that you want
FROM (subquery) t1 INNER JOIN (subquery{same as t1}) t2
ON t1.attribue = t2.attribte;
```

Note: this is a pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much easy with a CTE.

This example doesn't make much sense, it just shows *how* to do it:

```
SQL> with t1 as
  2    (select deptno
  3     from dept
  4    )
  5  select a.*
  6  from t1 a inner join t1 b on a.deptno = b.deptno;

    DEPTNO
----------
        10
        20
        30
        40

SQL>
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `WITH` clause. Thanks. Is there any other way we can do this?

Comment: Well, this is the simplest option. You could create a **view** which uses that "subquery" as a source, and then re-use the view in your SELECT statement, but it requires you to have CREATE VIEW privilege and you'd start having a lot of (probably) unnecessary views in your schema. I'd go with a CTE (a.k.a. the WITH factoring clause).